# Apex Salesforce Updating Field from Other Entity only getting 1 value on Bulk insert

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

Tried to make that title as specific as possible. Sorry if it is long.
Basically, what is happening is that I have a trigger that looks up a match (on email) to a custom object. If the email matches. I need to pull information from the custom object (Member Verification) and put that in a field (custom field) on the Lead object.

This is working fine for individuals. But when I do a bulk import, every Lead ends up with the same value, instead of the unique value that it should be matching by email address. I have tried about 6 different methods, and all of them look like they should work. But I have no idea what I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is below:

```
trigger UpdateVerifyLead on Lead (before insert, before update) {
List<String> leadEmails = new List<String>();

Map<String, Member_Verification__c > MVEmailMap = new  Map<String, Member_Verification__c >(
    [SELECT Id, Primary_Email__c,TFA_Salesforce_ID__C FROM Member_Verification__c WHERE Primary_Email__c != null and Primary_Email__c IN :leadEmails]);

for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
    leadEmails.add(lead.Email);

for(Lead leadObj:Trigger.new){
    if(MVEmailmap.containsKey(leadObj.Email)){
        lead.TFA_Salesforce_ID__c = MVEmailmap.get(leadObj.Email).TFA_Salesforce_ID__C ;
        lead.Verified__c = True;
        MVEmailmap.clear();
    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're instantiating the map using a query, which is fine if you need to [have Ids as keys](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=maps%7CMaps%7Cmap%7CMap%7Cmapping%7Cmappings%7Cmapped%7CMapping%7CMAp#apex_System_Map_ctor), but I'm not sure it works with your email field as a key.

You'll need an extra iteration to populate the map.

Something like this should work:

```
   trigger UpdateVerifyLead on Lead (before insert, before update) {

     List<String> leadEmails = new List<String>();
     Map<String, Member_Verification__c> MVEmailMap = new  Map<String, Member_Verification__c>();

     // first iteration to get the emails
     for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
       leadEmails.add(lead.Email);
     }

     // populate the map, dropping the != null, shouldn't be necessary
     for(Member_Verification__c memberVerification:[SELECT Id, Primary_Email__c,TFA_Salesforce_ID__C FROM Member_Verification__c WHERE Primary_Email__c IN :leadEmails]){
         MVEmailMap.put(memberVerification.Primary_Email__c,memberVerification);
     }

     // final iteration to set the member verification
     for(Lead leadObj:Trigger.new){
         if(MVEmailmap.containsKey(leadObj.Email)){
             lead.TFA_Salesforce_ID__c = MVEmailmap.get(leadObj.Email).TFA_Salesforce_ID__C;
             lead.Verified__c = True;
          }
     }
  }
```